# clang warns that `ffi_type` is not compatible with `sizeof`

Tags: c, clang-tidy

I am using [`libffi`](https://github.com/libffi/libffi) in C and receive a warning from `clang-tidy` that I do not quite understand.

I am allocating memory on the heap for an array of elements of type `ffi_type`:

```
ffi_type **arg_types = malloc(num_total_args * sizeof(ffi_type));
```

and receive the following warning:

```
Result of 'malloc' is converted to a pointer of type 'ffi_type *', which is incompatible with sizeof operand type 'ffi_type'
```

Could somebody give me a hint, how to fix it? The actual definition of the `ffi_type` is

```c
typedef struct _ffi_type
{
  size_t size;
  unsigned short alignment;
  unsigned short type;
  struct _ffi_type **elements;
} ffi_type;
```

and actually it is not clear to me, why it is incompatible with the sizeof operator.

UPDATE: Helpful comments by @IanAbbot, @Toby Speight, @dbush helped me realized the (quite silly actually) issue. It must be

```
ffi_type **arg_types = malloc(num_total_args * sizeof(ffi_type *));
```

(mind the last asterisk), as the array is of elements of type `ffi_type *`.

Comment: Are you trying to allocate space for an array of `ffi_type*` or an array of `ffi_type`? EDIT: Your question says you are allocating space for an array of `ffi_type`, so you need `ffi_type *arg_types` to point to the first element.

Comment: That's one reason we normally write `arg_types = malloc(num_total_args * sizeof *arg_types)` instead of repeating the type in the size calculation.  Easier to get it right, and keep it right that way!

Comment: Some parts of the libffi API use an array of `ffi_type` and some parts use an array of `ffi_type *`.

Comment: @IanAbbott, yeah, it's my typo, I am creating an array of type `ffi_type *`. I have realized that it should be `sizeof(ffi_type *`) instead of `sizeof(ffi_type)`.

Comment: @TobySpeight, cool, I did not know that it is possible in C!

Comment: @TobySpeight, actually `clang-tidy` complaints now too: `error: suspicious usage of 'sizeof(A*)'; pointer to aggregate [bugprone-sizeof-expression,-warnings-as-errors]`

Comment: That's probably worth reporting as a bug, since it's the common idiom to _avoid_ such errors.

Comment: @TobySpeight, good point, I'll do it today

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're allocating space for an array of type `ffi_type`, but assigning the result to a variable of type `ffi_type **` which can hold an array of type `ffi_type *`.  That's what you're being warned about.

Change the type of the `sizeof` expression to match the intended usage.

```
ffi_type **arg_types = malloc(num_total_args * sizeof(ffi_type *));
```

Or better yet (as it doesn't depend on the type of `arg_types`):

```
ffi_type **arg_types = malloc(num_total_args * sizeof *arg_types);
```

Comment: Or, if you intended an array of pointers, `sizeof (ffi_type*)`.  Or (better), in any case, adapt to what you're assigning to: `sizeof *arg_types`.

Comment: Yes, but I actually need the array of elements of type `ffi_type *`, because this is what `libffi` wants.

Comment: Ah, OK, I have realized that I need to change sizeof's operand to `ffi_type *`! Silly mistake, I wonder how the code works at all (and it works actually). UPDATE: it works as the pointer needs less memory than the actual `struct ffi_type`

Comment: @dbush, thank you! In your answer, in the first solution one asterisk on the left-hand side is missing. The second solution leads to another warning from `clang-tidy` (suspisous usage of sizeof), so I went with the first solution.